# How to solve this efficiently?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two arrays:

1. `score[n]`
2. `pos[n]`, where n <= 10^5; pos[i],score[i] <= 10^4

Define:

```
f(i,j) = abs(pos[i]-pos[j])*max(score[i],score[j])
```

I need to find sum of `f(i,j)` for all `i,j`s.
I have an algorithm that can solve it in `O(n^2)` but i want to optimize.
I have spent much time but could not.

Any help is appreciated. 
Worst case code
http://ideone.com/q4qSNh

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or snippets of your code for better context please?

Comment: Your function f is symmetric in i and j, i.e. f(i,j) = f(j,i) so a simple optimization is to only evaluate a triangle and then double the result. Still O(n^2) but only half the effort.

Comment: I have considered that

Comment: Provide your code then this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have added ideone link of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question asked earlier. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206083/attraction-force-as-coding).

@Gribouillis has provided a nice algorithm which has `O(nlogn)` complexity, consisting of sorting and using balanced binary search trees. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206083/attraction-force-as-coding/41208135#41208135) for the complete answer

Implementation has been left as an exercise.